# What is the JavaScript >>> operator used for?

Tags: javascript, operators

What does the JavaScript `>>>` operator do?

For example, `alert(1 >>> 2)`.

How do we use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a bitwise operator, here is an explanation taken from [this page](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/bitwise_operators.html).

> This is the zero-fill right shift
>   operator which shifts the binary
>   representation of the first operand to
>   the right by the number of places
>   specified by the second operand. Bits
>   shifted off to the right are discarded
>   and zeroes are added on to the left.
>   With a positive number you would get
>   the same result as with the
>   sign-propagating right shift operator,
>   but negative numbers lose their sign
>   becoming positive as in the next
>   example, which (assuming 'a' to be
>   -13) would return 1073741820:

Watch out though, bitwise operators are pretty slow in JavaScript.

Comment: +1 looking at the same page :)

Comment: That last line is a little misguided.  They're not *particularly* slow in modern implementations and you'll often find that they're a faster alternative to less concise methods.

Comment: Ah, I was going on what Douglas Crockford said in `JavaScript: The good parts`. He says to avoid them because of their speed. You are probably right though, V8 seems to be quick at just about everything.

Answer (score 8):

It's the zero-fill right shift operator (as opposed to the sign-propagating right shift, `>>`).